# pyomo creating constraints via a loop

Tags: pyomo

I am adding a series of constraints like this, one for each node (Node_A, Node_B, ... Node_L):

```
def NodeA(model):
    k = sum(
        model.ArcVar[i] * node_arc_matrix[i,0]
        for i in model.ArcVar
            )
    return k ==  2*model.NodeVar[1]
model.NodeAConstraint=Constraint(rule=NodeA)
```

Where the 0-index in node_arc_matrix refers to the column corresponding to Node_A, and model.NodeVar[1] refers to Node-A as well.  Instead of creating a constraint for each node manually can I create constraints across both i (arcs) and j (nodes)?

Answer (score 2):

No need to add a loop.

When you have elements in your constraint that are a "for all element in ...", Pyomo simply requires you to add the `Set`s that you want to iterate over in the `Constraint` construction line.

```
model.NodeAConstraint=Constraint(model.set_of_arcs_A, model.set_of_node_N, rule=NodeA)
```

And your rule must include `a` and `n` as parameters (`i` seems to already be used in your function).

```
def NodeA(model, a, n):
    k = sum(
        model.ArcVar[i] * node_arc_matrix[i,a]
        for i in model.ArcVar
    )
    return k ==  2 * model.NodeVar[n]
```

Notice where I put `a` and `n` in the previous code. It also needs to be parameters for your function. I tried replacing every `0` by `a` and every `1` by `n`, if I understood your needs correctly.

Link to documentation here: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Constraints.html